# Python - Regex find second match first

Tags: python, regex

I have a little problem with Python regex.

I need to find name of the function in this string: (the (number) arent in the string in my file)

```
(1)void f(int test);
(2)void h(int test);
(3)double f(int test1, int test2, ...);
(4)double f(int test1, int test2);
```

I have this code:

```
namePattern = "^[\s\S]*?\s?[*\s]*([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)\s*\([\S\s]*?\).*?$"
functionName = re.sub(re.compile(namePattern, re.MULTILINE), r'\1', funcString)
```

when I print the functionName, it prints firstly the (3) **f** function, when I need firstly to write (1) **f** function.

Can anyone plesase help me to esure that regex will find (1) **f** function first? Thanks.

BTW I cant understand why it find firstly the second function **f** function. Not the first, not the last, but the second. It's weird.

Comment: Cannot seem to replicate the problem: https://regex101.com/r/oI6aU6/1. Match information on the right shows that all functions are indeed being matched

Comment: On regex101 I have the same output. Altough in Python its how I posted :/

Comment: Can you copy paste the output word to word so we can understand it better

Comment: It works perfect in Python interpreter as well

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.findall` with following regex :

```
>>> s="""(1)void f(int test);
... (2)void h(int test);
... (3)double f(int test1, int test2, ...);
... (4)double f(int test1, int test2);"""

>>> re.findall(r'(\(\d\))[^( ]*(.*)\(',s)
[('(1)', ' f'), ('(2)', ' h'), ('(3)', ' f'), ('(4)', ' f')]
```

The regex `r'(\(\d\))[^( ]*(.*)\('` is contain 2 capture grouping first is `(\(\d\))` that will match a digit within a parenthesis and second is `(.*)` that will match any thing before `(` and after `[^( ]*`